# How to end a definition of a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, function

I have am trying to define a function but I don't know how to end it; it's causing my next function to be in the first function's body. Here's a chunk of the code:

```
def save(name):
    if x['fname'] == 'ply.json':
        save1(name)
    else: write_data({'fname':'ply.json', 'name':name}, 'ply.json')

def incrace():
    race=raw_input()
    if race.lower() == "avian":
        print "Great %s! So you would like to be an" % (name),
        print race.lower(),
        print "?"
    elif race.lower() == "apex":
        print "Great %s! So you would like to be an" % (name),
        print race.lower(),
        print "?"
    elif race.lower() == "human":
        print "Great %s! So you would like to be a" % (name),
        print race.lower(),
        print "?"
    elif race.lower() == "floran":
        print "Great %s! So you would like to be a" % (name),
        print race.lower(),
        print "?"
    elif race.lower() == "glitch":
        print "Great %s! So you would like to be a" % (name),
        print race.lower(),
        print "?"
    elif race.lower() == "hylotl":
        print "Great %s! So you would like to be a" % (name),
        print race.lower(),
        print "?"
    else:
        print "Sorry, what was that? You're what race?"
        incrace()
```

Here's where I'm having issues:

```
>>>def save(name):
...    if x['fname'] == 'ply.json':
...        save1(name)
...    else:
...        write_data({'fname':'ply.json', 'name':name}, 'ply.json')
...
...def incrace():
  File "<stdin>", line 6
    def incrace()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've been searching for a while but I've no idea how to end the function. I've had the problem previously but how I fixed it I've no idea to either. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you actually had that blank line between the functions, that should have worked.

Comment: @user2357112 I suspect that there's probably whitespace on that blank line...

Comment: @MattDMo: Looks like it. Whitespace shows up in the code snippet in the edit view, though not in the interpreter session or the displayed text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working in IDLE or the Python shell, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to get back to the `>>>` prompt, then begin your next function definition.

The only time you wouldn't do this is if you were working on a class definition, in that case you'd leave a single blank line between function defs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Vim editor and run with command..
In my view, I'm confidence with Vim to avoid such kind of errors